# Is the the complement of the Halting problem NP-hard

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, np-hard

Let us define the language (the complement of the Halting Problem):

$$
LOOPING = \left\{ \langle M,x \rangle | M \ doesn't \ halt \ on \ x\right\}
$$

The question is if $LOOPING$ is NP-Hard.
I'm pretty clueless about the answer. I know the the Halting problem is NP-Hard, but I can't seem to find a reduction from an NP-Hard problem to $LOOPING$.

Comment: Hint: Construct a Turing machine which goes over all potential satisfying assignments of a SAT instance, halts if it doesn't find any, and enters an infinite loop otherwise.

Comment: I think you mean "$M$ *doesn't* halt on $x$".

Comment: You're right, thanks I corrected the question.

Comment: Mind correcting the grammar? Halt(s)

Comment: So Yuval the reduction you suggested is polynomial because M is of finite length and x depends on the input of the SAT-problem?

Comment: the complement of Halting Problem is not in r.e. You can not make a Turing machine given <M>w and decide whether it will go in a loop. But if you define your input like the input of TMSAT then you can decide it. I suggest you see definition of TMSAT.